# Is there way to tell Mercurial to put .orig files into a separate directory?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I don't like Mercurial polluting the source tree with .orig files and such. Is it possible to keep all such files in /tmp, for example?

Comment: hg doesn't do that on any of the installs I've used - are you sure it's not another process

Comment: There is even a stackoverflow thread about a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067680/how-to-automatically-remove-all-orig-files-in-mercurial-working-tree

Comment: That's why I thought Mercurial does it.

Comment: Though I'm not doing a merge, so it may be a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

The question to which you link: [How to automatically remove all .orig files in Mercurial working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067680/how-to-automatically-remove-all-orig-files-in-mercurial-working-tree) has an answer that suggests using an update hook to delete the files automatically, which you could very easily turn to a 'mv'.  That would be automatic and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's mercurial doing that, it might just be your merge programs.
If it's mercurial, I'm sure it's not currently configurable.

Comment: The revert command makes `.orig` files unless you use `--no-backup`.

Comment: I believe the issue is Kdiff3 [bundled w tortoise Hg] (or maybe another merge tool) .. In kDiff3, If you look under SETTINGS > CONFIGURE kDiff3 > DIRECTORY... the last option is "backup file (.orig)" - If you uncheck this KD3 will not write the file - I don't think you "need" is as Hg is keeping a record 'pre merge' anyway - can someone else more experienced in distributed SC please weight in on this ... thx

Comment: @jpmyob: THANK YOU!  Even after going with the --no-backup change, I was still seeing new .orig files being created.  Updating kdiff3's setting is the additional step I was missing -- all is well now.