# Using hg revert in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial. I made a clone of a repository. For debugging, I changed a few lines of code in a java file. I did not commit those changes though. I just want to revert them back to their original state, as found in the repository. I tried `hg revert filename.java`, which did revert it, but now when I do `hg status`, I see additional files added in my folder now like:

```
? filename.java.orig
```

Can I just delete those files, and why does Mercurial make them when I use revert?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can delete them. It's a safety feature in case you reverted something you didn't mean to revert.

Answer (score 88):

You can also use the flag --no-backup and the .orig files will not be created

```
hg revert --no-backup filename.java
```

As of Mercurial 2.0, you can instead use the flag -C to supress the .orig files from being created

```
hg revert -C filename.java
```

Comment: Save some typing with: `hg revert -C filename.java`

Comment: The -C shortcut was introduced with mercurial 2.0 see http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `-C` is short for `--no-backup`... is it a `C`ourageous revert?

Comment: I guess it stands for clean, since it has the same effect as calling `hg revert FILE && hg clean`.

Answer (score 23):

I find the [purge extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension) handy.  Usage:

```
hg purge
```

> "This extension purges all files and directories not being tracked by
> Mercurial"

...including the .orig files but excluding ignored files (unless you use --all).

Answer (score 8):

As other's have pointed out, you can safely delete these files.

You can remove them by executing this command from the root of your repo:

```
rm `hg st -un | grep orig`
```

If you want to revert, and don't care at all about backing up the original files, the command you want is:

```
hg update -C
```

Answer (score 6):

Those are copies of the files from before you reverted them. If you don't need those, you can delete them, either by hand or by using the [*Purge* extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension):

```
hg clean
```

Comment: There is "clean" command in standard Mercurial -- perhaps you are thinking of the purge extension and `hg purge`?

Comment: @Martin: Typing `hg clean` says that `clean` is provided by the purge extension

Comment: Casebash: ah, right -- the purge extension provides the command under both names: `hg purge` and `hg clean`.

Answer (score 5):

These backup files can be created for merge and revert operations (cf. [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html)). You can add an ignore rule if you want, or simply delete them if you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

These are rather common, resulting from various operations. A glance at one of the moderate sized repositories I work on finds 237 of them. I don't like deleting things that may end up being useful, and I have no reason to name legitimate files with the same suffix, so I add the following to .hgignore instead:

```
.\.orig$
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this batch file myself.

```
IF "%1%" == "d" (
    del /s *.orig
    del /s *.rej
 ) ELSE ( 
    del /s /p *.rej
    del /s /p *.orig
 )
```

Help:
Save this content as **orig.bat**

1. Run **`orig d`** to delete all rejects and orig files at once without confirmation
2. Run **`orig`** to delete files with confirmation [Safety mechanism]

Hope this is helpful.