# How can I backout of a Mercurial changeset in a working directory and not commit it to the repo?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

> Backout works by applying a changeset that's the opposite of the
>   changeset to be backed out. That new changeset is committed to the
>   repository, and eventually merged.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout

How can I backout without commiting the changeset? I just want the changeset reverted in a working directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using hg revert in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239331/using-hg-revert-in-mercurial)

Comment: Did you already commit changes, or do you just have modified files in your working directory which are not yet committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hg backout --no-commit REV

This will perform the backout but leave the changes uncommited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already committed a new changeset *but not yet pushed it*; let's say your history looks like this:

`A--B--C--★`

where C is the recently committed changeset you wish to do away with, but leave its modifications in the working folder. And ★ is the working directory (not an actual changeset itself).

There is more than one way to do this. One approach is the following...

`hg up B`

This leaves your history looking like this:

```
A--B--★
    \
     C
```

Then do

`hg revert -r C`

which in effect copies whatever changes were in C into your working folder.

Then you could do (optional)

`hg strip C`

which eradicates C from history:

`A--B--★`

An advantage of this approach is that it removes C entirely, like it never existed.

(I mentioned that using `strip` is optional in this sense: if you did leave C in place, it causes little harm. And you'd never need to push it if it is marked secret. But personally I would clean it up by stripping.)