# How do you prevent mercurial from leaving .orig files after a merge?

Tags: merge, mercurial

My question is simple: Mercurial leaves .orig files after performing a merge (or histedit, etc.) I want to **prevent** this from occurring.

This has been discussed before, but without a satisfactory answer. For instance, [How do you disable mercurial from leaving .orig files after a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429332/how-do-you-disable-mercurial-from-leaving-orig-files-after-a-merge) discusses close to this exact issue, but the accepted answer deals only with `hg revert`, and does not (as of today) fix issues with merge.

Similarly, [How to automatically remove all .orig files in Mercurial working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067680/how-to-automatically-remove-all-orig-files-in-mercurial-working-tree) discusses how to get rid of the files once they're there, but I want a solution that prevents them from appearing in the first place.

I'm aware of `origbackuppath`, which can be used to shuffle the files off to another directory, but that still requires a cron job to get rid of them, so it's not a solution unless there's a /dev/null-equivalent for directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable mercurial from leaving .orig files after a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429332/how-do-you-disable-mercurial-from-leaving-orig-files-after-a-merge)

Comment: Its a shame the other question has an accepted answer which blatantly does not answer the question.